# How to repeat elements of an array along two axes?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to repeat elements of an array along axis 0 and axis 1 for M and N times respectively:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
b = a.repeat(2, 0).repeat(2, 1)
print(b)

[[ 0  0  1  1  2  2  3  3]
 [ 0  0  1  1  2  2  3  3]
 [ 4  4  5  5  6  6  7  7]
 [ 4  4  5  5  6  6  7  7]
 [ 8  8  9  9 10 10 11 11]
 [ 8  8  9  9 10 10 11 11]]
```

This works, but I want to know are there better methods without create a temporary array.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), see [`numpy.kron`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html):

```
>>> a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
>>> print(np.kron(a, np.ones((2,2), dtype=a.dtype)))
[[ 0  0  1  1  2  2  3  3]
 [ 0  0  1  1  2  2  3  3]
 [ 4  4  5  5  6  6  7  7]
 [ 4  4  5  5  6  6  7  7]
 [ 8  8  9  9 10 10 11 11]
 [ 8  8  9  9 10 10 11 11]]
```

Your original method is OK too, though!

Answer (score 11):

You can make use of **`np.broadcast_to`** here:

```
def broadcast_tile(a, h, w):
    x, y = a.shape
    m, n = x * h, y * w
    return np.broadcast_to(
        a.reshape(x, 1, y, 1), (x, h, y, w)
    ).reshape(m, n)

broadcast_tile(a, 2, 2)
```

```
array([[ 0,  0,  1,  1,  2,  2,  3,  3],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  1,  2,  2,  3,  3],
       [ 4,  4,  5,  5,  6,  6,  7,  7],
       [ 4,  4,  5,  5,  6,  6,  7,  7],
       [ 8,  8,  9,  9, 10, 10, 11, 11],
       [ 8,  8,  9,  9, 10, 10, 11, 11]])
```

***Performance***

---

***Functions***

```python
def chris(a, h, w):
    x, y = a.shape
    m, n = x * h, y * w
    return np.broadcast_to(
        a.reshape(x, 1, y, 1), (x, h, y, w)
    ).reshape(m, n)

def alex_riley(a, b0, b1):
    r, c = a.shape
    rs, cs = a.strides
    x = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, (r, b0, c, b1), (rs, 0, cs, 0))
    return x.reshape(r*b0, c*b1)

def paul_panzer(a, b0, b1):
    r, c = a.shape
    out = np.empty((r, b0, c, b1), a.dtype)
    out[...] = a[:, None, :, None]
    return out.reshape(r*b0, c*b1)

def wim(a, h, w):
    return np.kron(a, np.ones((h,w), dtype=a.dtype))
```

***Setup***

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from timeit import timeit

res = pd.DataFrame(
       index=['chris', 'alex_riley', 'paul_panzer', 'wim'],
       columns=[5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 500, 1000],
       dtype=float
)

a = np.arange(100).reshape((10,10))

for f in res.index:
    for c in res.columns:
        h = w = c
        stmt = '{}(a, h, w)'.format(f)
        setp = 'from __main__ import h, w, a, {}'.format(f)
        res.at[f, c] = timeit(stmt, setp, number=50)
```

***Output***

[image]

Comment: Nice summary. A few oversights in your (assuming you are Chris) function: (1) first argument `arr` is not used in body (2) `m//(h*x)` and  `n//(w*y)` are both just `1`; similarly, `m//h` and `n//w` are just `x` and `y`.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Well that certainly made the reshaping a lot more readable, thanks.  Very nice answer btw!

Comment: Could you please include the command to generate the plot?  I'm not yet very familiar with panda.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Since the result cannot be implemented as a view, `as_strided` offers no benefits over simple preallocation and broadcasting. Because of its overhead `as_strided` seems in fact a bit slower (I did no proper benchmarking, though).

The `as_strided` code is taken from [@AlexRiley's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32848377).

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
import numpy as np

def tile_array(a, b0, b1):
    r, c = a.shape                                    # number of rows/columns
    rs, cs = a.strides                                # row/column strides 
    x = as_strided(a, (r, b0, c, b1), (rs, 0, cs, 0)) # view a as larger 4D array
    return x.reshape(r*b0, c*b1)                      # create new 2D array

def tile_array_pp(a, b0, b1):
    r, c = a.shape
    out = np.empty((r, b0, c, b1), a.dtype)
    out[...] = a[:, None, :, None]
    return out.reshape(r*b0, c*b1)

a = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)

kwds = {'globals': {'f_ar': tile_array, 'f_pp': tile_array_pp, 'a': a},
        'number': 1000}

from timeit import timeit

print('as_strided', timeit('f_ar(a, 100, 100)', **kwds))
print('broadcast ', timeit('f_pp(a, 100, 100)', **kwds))
```

Sample run:

```
as_strided 0.048387714981799945
broadcast  0.04324757700669579
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use `as_strided`. `kron` is much slower then using `repeat` twice. I have found that `as_strided` is much faster than a double `repeat` in many cases (small arrays [<250x250] with only a doubling in each dimension `as_strided` was slower). The `as_strided` trick is as follows:

```
a = arange(1000000).reshape((1000, 1000)) # dummy data

from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
N, M = 4,3 # number of time to replicate each point in each dimension
H, W = a.shape
b = as_strided(a, (H, N, W, M), (a.strides[0], 0, a.strides[1], 0)).reshape((H*N, W*M))
```

This works by using 0-length strides which causes numpy to read the same value multiple times (until it gets to the next dimension). The final `reshape` does copy the data, but only once unlike using a double `repeat` which will copy the data twice.

Comment: [Here's the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32848377/3923281) to the solution where `as_strided` was proposed, along with timings ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Errata: I'm only taking 2x upsampling into account.

TL;DR It turns out that after the OpenCV version,

```
np.repeat(np.repeat(a, 2, axis=1), 2, axis=0)
```

is the fastest. So the answer is - there's no faster ways in numpy today,
but you can get a slight improvement by changing the order of axes.

And if you don't mind OpenCV -

```
cv.resize(a, None, fx=2, fy=2, interpolation=cv.INTER_NEAREST)
```

Here is the test.

```
import timeit
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
test = np.zeros((16, 16, 3), dtype=np.float32)

def measure(f):
    t = timeit.timeit("f(test)", number=1000, globals={"test": test, "f": f})
    print("%s - %f"%(f.__name__, t))
    return f, t

def fastest(c):
    print(c.__name__)
    winner, t = min((measure(getattr(c, ve)) for ve in dir(c) if ve.startswith("alg_")), key=lambda x: x[1])
    print("%s winner: %s - %f"%(c.__name__, winner.__name__, t))
    return winner

@fastest
class nn:
    def alg_01(a):
        return np.repeat(np.repeat(a, 2, axis=0), 2, axis=1)
    def alg_02(a):
        return np.repeat(np.repeat(a, 2, axis=1), 2, axis=0)
    def alg_03(a):
        b = a[:, None, :, None]
        b = np.concatenate((b, b), axis=1)
        b = np.concatenate((b, b), axis=3)
        return b.reshape(a.shape[0]<<1, a.shape[1]<<1, *a.shape[2:])
    def alg_04(a):
        b = a[:, None, :, None]
        b = np.concatenate((b, b), axis=3)
        b = np.concatenate((b, b), axis=1)
        return b.reshape(a.shape[0]<<1, a.shape[1]<<1, *a.shape[2:])
    def alg_05(a):
        return (a[:, None, :, None]*np.ones((1, 2, 1, 2)+((1,)*len(a.shape[2:])), dtype=np.float32)).reshape(a.shape[0]<<1, a.shape[1]<<1, *a.shape[2:])
    def alg_06(a):
        return cv.resize(a, None, fx=2, fy=2, interpolation=cv.INTER_NEAREST)
    def alg_07(a):
        return a[:, None, :, None][:, (0, 0)][:, :, :, (0, 0)].reshape(a.shape[0]<<1, a.shape[1]<<1, *a.shape[2:])
    def alg_08(a):
        return a[:, None, :, None][:, :, :, (0, 0)][:, (0, 0)].reshape(a.shape[0]<<1, a.shape[1]<<1, *a.shape[2:])
    def alg_09(a):
        return np.kron(a, np.ones((2, 2), dtype=np.float32))
    def alg_10(a):
        return np.broadcast_to(a[:, None, :, None], (a.shape[0], 2, a.shape[1], 2)+a.shape[2:]).reshape(a.shape[0]<<1, a.shape[1]<<1, *a.shape[2:])
    def alg_11(a):
        ret = np.empty((a.shape[0], 2, a.shape[1], 2, *a.shape[2:]), dtype=np.float32)
        ret[...] = a[:, None, :, None]
        ret.resize((a.shape[0]<<1, a.shape[1]<<1, *a.shape[2:]), refcheck=False)
        return ret
```

The result is:

```
nn
alg_01 - 0.040967
alg_02 - 0.033744
alg_03 - 0.057969
alg_04 - 0.048739
alg_05 - 0.076595
alg_06 - 0.078638
alg_07 - 0.084692
alg_08 - 0.084539
alg_09 - 0.344339
alg_10 - 0.078707
alg_11 - 0.049424
nn winner: alg_02 - 0.033744
```