# Resizing small images in Python (numpy) to a multiple of the original size, accurately

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to repeat along two axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656665/how-to-repeat-along-two-axis)

Let's suppose we have the following matrix/image:

```
x = array([[1, 0, 1],
           [0, 1, 0],
           [1, 0, 1]])
```

What I'd like to get is a 9x9 matrix that is a 3x magnified version of the above, having 3x3 ones in the top left corner, 3x3 0s in the middle top, etc.

The things I've already tried are:

**scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom**(x, 3, order=(anything)), for example order=0 returns this:

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

**scipy.misc.imresize**(x, (9,9), interp="nearest") (effectively from PIL), that comes up with a different creative (but wrong) solution.

Meanwhile, the MATLAB imresize solves the problem perfectly...

Any ideas? (note: all of these solutions *should* work, so before submitting, try it out :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kronecker product:

```
numpy.kron(x,numpy.ones((3,3)))
```

the result:

```
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Comment: @RobertSmith thanks, personally I find it more fun to use these mathematical tricks even if there are specially-tailored functions that can do the same. The code may be less comprehensible, though...

Comment: It could be less comprehensible but this is a good reason to remember the good old Kronecker product.