# Python function to expand image (NumPy array)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing

Say I have a greyscale image that is `3x3` and is represented by the `numpy` array below.

I want to increase the size and resolution of the image, similar to a resizing function in a normal picture editing software, but I don't want it to change any of the values of the pixels, just to expand them.

Is there a Python function that does the following conversion?

```
[0,0,0]
[0,1,0]
[0,0,0]
```

---->

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,1,1,0,0]
[0,0,1,1,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656665/how-to-repeat-along-two-axis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`np.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) along both axes of the 3x3 `img` array:

```
>>> img.repeat(2, axis=0).repeat(2, axis=1)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Another way is to calculate the [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of `img` and an array of the appropriate shape filled with ones:

```
>>> np.kron(img, np.ones((2,2)))
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Here's a link to the documentation for [`np.kron`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html):

So in the example above, each value `x` in `img` is multiplied by a 2x2 array of ones to create a 2x2 array of `x` values. These new 2x2 arrays make up the returned array.

This multiplication might be slower than simply repeating, however.