# Quick way to upsample numpy array by nearest neighbor tiling

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D array of integers that is *MxN*, and I would like to expand the array to *(BM)x(BN)* where *B* is the length of a square tile side thus each element of the input array is repeated as a *BxB* block in the final array. Below is an example with a nested for loop. Is there a quicker/builtin way?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(9).reshape([3,3])            # input array - 3x3
B=2.                                       # block size - 2  
A = np.zeros([a.shape[0]*B,a.shape[1]*B])  # output array - 6x6

# Loop, filling A with tiled values of a at each index
for i,l in enumerate(a):                   # lines in a
    for j,aij in enumerate(l):             # a[i,j]
        A[B*i:B*(i+1),B*j:B*(j+1)] = aij
```

Result ...

```
a=      [[0 1 2]
         [3 4 5]
         [6 7 8]]

A =     [[ 0.  0.  1.  1.  2.  2.]
         [ 0.  0.  1.  1.  2.  2.]
         [ 3.  3.  4.  4.  5.  5.]
         [ 3.  3.  4.  4.  5.  5.]
         [ 6.  6.  7.  7.  8.  8.]
         [ 6.  6.  7.  7.  8.  8.]]
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

One option is

```
>>> a.repeat(2, axis=0).repeat(2, axis=1)
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5],
       [3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8],
       [6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8]])
```

This is slightly wasteful due to the intermediate array but it's concise at least.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a potentially fast way using stride tricks and reshaping:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

def tile_array(a, b0, b1):
    r, c = a.shape                                    # number of rows/columns
    rs, cs = a.strides                                # row/column strides 
    x = as_strided(a, (r, b0, c, b1), (rs, 0, cs, 0)) # view a as larger 4D array
    return x.reshape(r*b0, c*b1)                      # create new 2D array
```

The underlying data in `a` is copied when `reshape` is called, so this function does not return a view. However, compared to using `repeat` along multiple axes, fewer copying operations are required.

The function can be then used as follows:

```
>>> a = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

>>> tile_array(a, 2, 2)
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5],
       [3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8],
       [6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8]])

>>> tile_array(a, 3, 4)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8],
       [6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8],
       [6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8]])
```

Now, for *small* blocks, this method is a little slower than using `repeat` but faster than `kron`.

For slightly larger blocks, however, it becomes quicker than other alternatives. For instance, using a block shape of `(20, 20)`:

```
>>> %timeit tile_array(a, 20, 20)
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.7 µs per loop

>>> %timeit a.repeat(20, axis=0).repeat(20, axis=1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 26 µs per loop

>>> %timeit np.kron(a, np.ones((20,20), a.dtype))
10000 loops, best of 3: 106 µs per loop
```

The gap between the methods increases as the block size increases.

Also if `a` is a large array, it may be quicker than alternatives:

```
>>> a2 = np.arange(1000000).reshape(1000, 1000)
>>> %timeit tile_array(a2, 2, 2)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.4 ms per loop

>>> %timeit a2.repeat(2, axis=0).repeat(2, axis=1)
1 loops, best of 3: 30.9 ms per loop
```

Comment: a.repeat(20,1).repeat(20,0) is 5x faster than a.repeat(20,0).repeat(20,1).

Answer (score 6):

Probably not the fastest, but..

```
np.kron(a, np.ones((B,B), a.dtype))
```

It does the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), so it involves a multiplication for each element in the output.