# How to "inflate" an array in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array that looks like, for example

```
01
23
```

I want to "inflate" it so that the resulting array looks like

```
0 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 1
2 2 2 3 3 3
2 2 2 3 3 3
2 2 2 3 3 3
```

I've played around with numpy `tile` and various reps and axes, but nothing gives me quite what I want.  I can see how to do this with nested loops, but I'm looking for a "pythonic" way to accomplish this.  Anyone know how?  And BTW, the real problem I am dealing with involves a 3D array.

Comment: For a 3D problem, consider adding in a sample. It could be re-opened if the dup target doesn't translate well for that case.

Comment: @Divakar Bah.  I answered before looking for a duplicate.  I don't answer in the numpy tag often, so I jumped on the opportunity when I knew the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using [`numpy.kron`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html) - the Kronecker product of two matrices.  The first matrix will be the original one that you have, and second matrix is simply a 3 x 3 `np.ones` array:

```
In [3]: import numpy as np

In [4]: A = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3]])

In [5]: B = np.kron(A, np.ones((3, 3), dtype=A.dtype))

In [6]: B
Out[6]:
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  3.,  3.,  3.]])
```

Note that I'm ensuring that the output matrix `B` respects the original type of data that `A` was created with.  I'm not sure what type your original matrix was, so I've put that in to respect whatever the type was originally so I've made sure to create the `ones` matrix to respect the same type as `A` to ensure that `B` also conforms to the same type.

In general, to create a `N x N` repeated tile of each element in your input matrix, change the `3` in the `np.ones` call to `N`.

Comment: There are better ways as suggested in dup one. For this one to keep same dtype : `np.ones((3, 3),dtype=A.dtype)`.

Comment: @Divakar That's a good idea.  I assumed the input was `numpy.float`.  I'll change my post.  However, the duplicate only has two answers - one of them with `kron`.  I am not particularly fond of the second answer... though the timing is very attractive!

Comment: @Divakar I would have used this link as the better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846846/quick-way-to-upsample-numpy-array-by-nearest-neighbor-tiling/32848377