# Upscaling a numpy array and evenly distributing values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2 dimensional numpy array representing spatial data. I need to increase its resolution. I also need to evenly distribute values across the space. For example, a value of

5

would become:

1.25 1.25

1.25 1.25

I've looked at imresize but I don't think the interpolation options will work for this. Maybe there's another way? I'd like to avoid iterating rows and columns if I can. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Simply divide by the number of elements in the block defined by its height and width and then replicate/ expand. To replicate, we can use `np.repeat` or `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`.

With [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) -

```
def upscale_repeat(a, h, w):
    return (a/float(h*w)).repeat(h, axis=0).repeat(h, axis=1)
```

With [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) using [`tile_array`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32848377/3293881) -

```
def upscale_strided(a, h, w):
    return tile_array(a/float(h*w), h, w)
```

Sample run -

```
In [140]: a
Out[140]: 
array([[ 7,  6,  9],
       [ 6,  6, 10]])

In [141]: upscale_repeat(a, 2, 2)
Out[141]: 
array([[ 1.75,  1.75,  1.5 ,  1.5 ,  2.25,  2.25],
       [ 1.75,  1.75,  1.5 ,  1.5 ,  2.25,  2.25],
       [ 1.5 ,  1.5 ,  1.5 ,  1.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ],
       [ 1.5 ,  1.5 ,  1.5 ,  1.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ]])

In [142]: upscale_repeat(a, 2, 3)
Out[142]: 
array([[ 1.17,  1.17,  1.17,  1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  1.5 ,  1.5 ,  1.5 ],
       [ 1.17,  1.17,  1.17,  1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  1.5 ,  1.5 ,  1.5 ],
       [ 1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  1.67,  1.67,  1.67],
       [ 1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  1.67,  1.67,  1.67]])
```