# Repeat a NumPy array in multiple dimensions at once?

Tags: python, numpy

```
np.repeat(np.repeat([[1, 2, 3]], 3, axis=0), 3, axis=1)
```

works as expected and produces

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]])
```

However,

```
np.repeat([[1, 2, 3]], [3, 3])
```

and

```
np.repeat([[1, 2, 3]], [3, 3], axis=0)
```

produce errors.

Is it possible to `repeat` an array in multiple dimensions at once?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want a shorter way to produce the output of your first program, right?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Yes, a single invocation of `np.repeat` preferably. You'd think that one of the other examples should work.

Comment: Is it a performance requirement that you are looking to do so or just shorter code or something else?

Comment: @Divakar it felt like maybe I'm not using `repeat` correctly, or the API is warty.

Comment: This is a totally valid use of `repeat`. Another method you could do would be to broadcast and then reshape. For e.g. with your `x` defined above, `np.broadcast_to(x.T, (3, 3, 3)).reshape((3, 9))` would do the same.

Comment: Don't think `np.repeat` would do so in one call. So, basically the answer to your question would be - No. As such, I would like to close this question. If you are looking for alternatives, that's a different story.

Comment: I can produce that result several other ways (one repeat with reshape and transpose, `kron`, etc), but this double repeat is hands down the speed winner.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656665/how-to-repeat-elements-of-an-array-along-two-axes which has significantly more answers and analysis than this one. The fastest is a stride trick, but `kron` is by far the slowest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, I think the original method you propose is totally fine. It's readable, it makes sense, and it's not very slow.

You could use the `repeat` *method* instead of function which reads a bit more nicely:

```
>>> x.repeat(3, 1).repeat(3, 0)
array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]])
```

With numpy's broadcasting rules, there's likely dozens of ways to create the repeated data and throw it around into the shape you want, too. One approach could be to use `np.broadcast_to()` and repeat the data in `D+1` dimensions, where `D` is the dimension you need, and then collapse it down to `D`.

For example:

```
>>> x = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])
>>> np.broadcast_to(x.T, (3, 3, 3)).reshape((3, 9))
array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]])
```

And without reshaping (so that you don't need to know the final length):

```
>>> np.hstack(np.broadcast_to(x, (3, 3, 3)).T)
array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]])
```

And there's likely a dozen other ways to do this. But I still think your original version is more idiomatic, as throwing it into extra dimensions to collapse it down is weird.

Comment: Broadcasting also requires a lot more thought about where the repeated elements will end up compared to just `repeat`ing multiple times.

Answer (score -1):

It isn't possible, see [repeat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html). But you are using a array with the shape `(1,3)`, so you have to use:

```
np.repeat(X, [2], axis=0)
```

because `np.repeat(X, [2,2], axis=0)` needs shape `(2,3)`, e.g.

```
X = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7]])
np.repeat(X, [2, 5], axis=0)
```

the output looks like:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]
 [5 6 7]
 [5 6 7]
 [5 6 7]
 [5 6 7]]
```

This means `[2,5]` stands for [**2**, 5]:`2x first row` and [2, **5**]:`5x second row` (shape: `(2, *doesn't matter*)` because `axis=0` means you want to repeat the rows.
Therefore you first have to generate an array with the dimensions `(3, *)`, and then produce the next array.

If you want to repeat your array:

```
np.repeat(X2, [5], axis=0)
```

produces:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]]
```

because you have only a 1-dimensional array.

The first call of `np.repeat` produces a 2D-array, the second call duplicates the columns. If you want to use `np.repeat(X2, [5], axis=0)` you get the same result as you have mentioned in your post above, because you have to call `np.repeat` a second time on the output of `np.repeat(X2, [5], axis=0)`.

In my opinion your use of `np.repeat` is the easiest and best way to achieve your output.

---

Edit: Hopefully the answer is now more clearly

Comment: That is really cool, I had no idea you could do that with `repeat`. Also OP is using an array of shape (1, 3), not (1, 4). This isn't answering OPs question though; it needs to repeat over multiple axes at once.

Comment: I don't understand the answer. You say "it's possible", but your example is different from mine: both I and O.

Comment: `np.repeat([[1, 2, 3]], [3], axis=0)` does not produce the desired output

Comment: @MaxB: I'm sorry my answer is not completly clear, just give me a few seconds to improve it

Comment: @MaxB: `np.repeat([[1, 2, 3]], [5], axis=0)` will do the trick, but only repeats the rows, not the columns.

Comment: This is only repeating the array in one of its dimensions.

Comment: Yes, because the question was if it is possible to use something like `[3, 3]` to repeat the rows and columns in `np.repeat` --> Not possible as explained in my answer

Comment: @Albo no, the question was "Repeat a NumPy array in multiple dimensions at once?"

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds: I'm sorry, then this was my fault... thought it was about using `np.repeat` to do the trick... sorry